# Changing Woocommerce language without changing the language in Dashboard admin Wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want woocommerce to change the language to Vietnamese, but the wordpress admin page is still in English language?

How to do that? Thank a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the language files and then in functions file add the following code. It will trigger in your frontend.

```
//set Vietnamese locale
add_filter( 'locale', function($locale) {
    if ( !is_admin() ){
        $locale = "vi";
    }
    return $locale;
});
```